# Fluent UI v8: How to create a DetailsList with ChoiceGroup for each row

Tags: fluentui-react

I need to show a table with three columns. The first column is just a simple label. The second and third column contain one of two possible choices for each row. The expected behaviour is that only one of the coices can be selected for each row but all rows are independent. I am currently trying to use DetailsList and ChoiceGroup but I don't know how to correctly combine the two. In the end I need to extract all selections and performe some post processing.